# Instantiating spring bean objects

Tags: java, spring

I've been playing with Spring and had a quick question...

I have a loop within `class A` which instantiates new objects of `class B`. To do this I've used the `new` operator however I cannot reference any Spring beans injected into instances of `class B` as I get a null pointer exception. I think I understand that this would be due to spring not managing these instances as beans and therefore not being able to manage the lifecycle however I was just wondering what the best way to go about creating multiple instances would be i.e. should I used `appContext.getBean("beanA");` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - are right with your assumptions. Using `new` means spring doesn't manage the object.

Solutions can be:

- `appContext.getBean("beanA")`, where the bean is of scope "prototype". You obtain the `appContext` by injecting it, or by implementing `ApplicationContextAware`
- using `@Configurable` and apsectJ weaving. That way even objects instantiated with `new` become managed by spring (the weaver plugs into the compiler or the vm)
- using a [`lookup-method`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection) - it's the same as the first option (again requires prototype-scoped bean), but you get a method of your class that returns a new instance each time you call it.

Normally, however, you shouldn't need that. In the rare cases you do, I'd recommend the 3rd option.

Comment: Nice summary, and the third option is indeed easy.

Comment: @Bozho Thanks for the answer but could you please clarify why I shouldn't need to do this under normal circumstances? Thanks again

Comment: because normally all beans are singletons that don't hold state. This is of course a symptom of anemic data model, but that's how regular applications are structured. If you need your business objects to perform logic AND to have state, read about domain-driven design