# How to use spring managed bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a class `A` defined with `@Component` annotation, and its variables are define using `@Value` and `@Autowired` annotations. In configuration file, I am using component-scan, so I know that I can get Bean(Class `A`'s object) if I have the context object.

Now, my case is I am creating object of class `B` using reflection at runtime, while class `B` is using class `A`, how do I use class `A`? I suppose I could not just `new A()` inside class `B`'s method, then those inside `@Autowired` field will be `null`, right?

I know that if class `B` is instantiated in spring, then I could just have `@Autowired A` in class `B`.

Comment: Is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158812/instantiating-spring-bean-objects?